# Run excel macros on my server from android

Tags: android, excel

I have an excel spreadsheet that I have a lot of Macros in it. This spreadsheet is in my server and I need my android application to trigger the the run of the macros in the excel spreadsheet... Is there anyway to do that ? Any language  I can use in the middle between them to achieve what I want or any suggestions? The macros are too complicated to replicate in android

Thank you

Comment: You'd need to write a server application to listen for commands from your android device, which would then execute them in excel on the server. Python might be good for this... though I'm not sure how well it works with office...

Comment: Sure,  know about device call "some script" on my webserver. How what script is this? I cant find anything on the net where you can run excel macros from scripting language on a websever

Comment: You'd have to write it yourself, or find one. I sort of doubt that this specific of a solution has been developed before, or at least released.